# How can i make full refund in delayed chained payment?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have system in which we used delayed chain payment but if we have to refund the full amount to sender so how can we do with this?

Is there any API or example for this ???

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use the Adaptive payment's Refund API to achieve this where you can specify the paykey or the tracking id for full amount refund . For more information check [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) link